# How to prevent the execution of getter setter methods of inherited properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, prototype

**Scenario 1:**

```
//create a parent object
var parent = {}

// define a property prop1 on parent
parent.prop1 = 'value1'

parent.prop1 // will print 'value1'

// create a child object with parent as the prototype
var child = Object.create(parent)

child.prop1 // will print "value1"

// create prop1 on child 
child.prop1 = 'value updated'

child.prop1 // will print 'value updated'

parent.prop1 // will print "value1"
```

Here the `prop1` on `child` will shadow(or override) the `prop1` on `parent`

**Scenario 2:**

```
// define parent
var parent = {}

//define setter/getters for prop1
Object.defineProperty(parent, 'prop1', 
    {
        get: function () {
            console.log('inside getter of prop1'); 
            return this._prop1;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            console.log('inside setter of prop1');
            this._prop1 = val;
        }
    });

// define prop1 on parent
parent.prop1 = 'value1' // prints: inside setter of prop1

//access prop1
parent.prop1 // prints inside getter of prop1 and "value1"

// create a new object with parent as the prototype
var child = Object.create(parent)

// access prop1
child.prop1 // inside getter of prop1 "value1"

// update prop1 on child
child.prop1 = 'updated value'// inside setter of prop1
```

In the last step, just like in **scenario1**, I want `prop1` on `child` to override the `prop1` defined on `parent`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: As we did not define `prop1` on child, delete statement has no effect.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(child, "prop1", {value: 'updated value'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dandavis suggested, re-defining the property on the child is overriding the parent's property.

```
Object.defineProperty(child, "prop1", {value: 'updated value'});
```