# Different behaviour of Object.defineProperty() and object.prototype.functionName=something

Tags: javascript, object

```
   class Something {
    a() {

    }
    get b() {
        return "bValue"
    }
}
    Something.prototype.eef = "dfd";
    window.someValue = "parent value";
   /*
     
     */
    Object.defineProperty(Something.prototype,"abc",{
    enumerable:true,
    configurable:true,
    get:function(){
        debugger;
        return "parent value";
    },
    set : function(value){
        debugger;
        window.someValue=value;
    }
    });

    class Derived extends Something {
  
    get b() {
        return "inside child bValue"
    }
}
class Derived1 extends Something{
};

/*
    obj1=new Derived1();
    obj1.abc.   should be "parent value" 
     */
```

case 1: setting property abc in Derived class

```
       Derived.prototype.abc="child value"; 
     /* obj2=new Derived();
        obj2.abc    should be "child value" but getting "parent 
       value"
  */
```

case 2: setting property abc in Derived class using Object.defineProperty

```
   Object.defineProperty(Derived.prototype,"abc",{
   value:"child value",
   enumerable:true,
   configurable:true
   });

/* obj3=new Derived();
       obj3.abc    output is "child value" which is expected
      
 */
```

I am defining property on Derived class directly using the above two method.
I am expecting that when I create an object (obj=new Derived()) for both the cases and try to get abc property of class. Then I should get the same value ie. "child value" . But for my implementation I am somehow triggering the getter and setter defined on "abc" in parent class "Something" prototype which is not normal and because of this I am getting two different value for the two cases.The thing which I am not getting is how I can make changes to the prototype of parent through child.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add two snippets to illustrate the difference between the two behaviors?

Comment: "*because of this I am getting two different value for the two cases.*" - how so? Even if you are triggering the setter, it should store the `"child value"` in the global `window.someValue` and then return that same value still when accessing `obj.abc`.

Comment: edited my code to explain better.

Comment: "*I am not able to understand how we are able affect parent.prototype by changing something in child.prototype*" - does my answer address this adequately?

Comment: I changed the getter and setter a little bit  to explain it clearly. You can check the getter it should return "parent value" when instance of Something class is used to invoke abc property.Then I am adding abc property in Derived class prototype ,so instance of Derived class should invoke abc defined in its own class prototype.But is not the case when I am setting property through Derived.prototype.It is working    only when setting property through Object.defineProperty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296497/how-to-override-a-defined-get-property-on-a-prototype, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191499/how-to-prevent-the-execution-of-getter-setter-methods-of-inherited-properties-in

Comment: "*It is working only when setting property through `Object.defineProperty`*" - yes, that is expected. When you are using assignment syntax, you are *not* adding a property to the prototype object, you're just triggering the setter. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Yeah thats my question ,why Object.prototype is not adding property, but Object.defineProperty is able to do it. Is there a difference between how they add property to prototype.

Comment: The difference is not `Derived.prototype`, which is the same object in both operations. It's `=` vs `Object.defineProperty`. And yes, they do behave differently!

Answer (score 0):

> I am somehow triggering the getter and setter defined on "abc" in parent class "Something" which is not normal

It *is* the normal behaviour of assignment. You are assigning the `.abc` property on an object which inherits from `Something.prototype` on which the setter is defined. It doesn't make a difference whether the assignment target is a `new Something` instance or the `Derived.prototype` object for that - they both have the same prototype chain.

If you want to override a property with a setter/getter in a subclass, you have to use `Object.defineProperty` - or just define the override in the `class` declaration.